# How to download most popular artifacts in a remote repository

Tags: maven

I am setting up a internal maven repository in our department using JFrog artifactory.

The artifactory hosting server need to access internet to download artifacts, it also should be accessed by developers in our department, the sad truth is that developers working in a internal LAN which have no internet access at all, and our security policy doesn't allow making the artifactory host server connect to both internet and the internal LAN at same time.

I want to let artifactory host server connect to internet temporarily and download the most popular artifacts in central repository but with a limited total size. Currently, I have a mirror of central repository configurated.

How can I do this？

Comment: how do you define the popularity here?

Comment: @nullpointer most downloaded. http://search.maven.org/#stats

Comment: Maven central for sure. The paid version of jfrog allows you to schedule updates and create a cached repository. But since your company is so restrictive it would be still bad because when someone asks for a dependency that isn't at the server it fetches it from internet and store local but it must have internet access.